# Are professional publications and journal articles worthwhile to include in resume for specialty role in IT?

Tags: resume

I am currently updating my resume to reflect new responsibilities assumed in my current position. I am thinking of creating a new section on resume to include publications, professional journal articles, and Linked articles I have written in my profession of cybersecurity.  **Several have been well received by my professional network**, and I am working with editorial board of a professional organization to see if they are able to accept a publication for inclusion in their official magazine for members.

**For someone in an senior role, how worthwhile would these publications be considered?** Would future hiring managers see these as evidence of passion commitment, and well - honed communication ability?

Comment: It has been told to me that it is highly unlikely anyone is ever going to read past the first page of your cv. It has been my experience that on a number of occasions I have been asked for my linkden and/or github when it is the literal first thing on my cv. Making me think the whole concept of a resume is one big exercise in futility.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely won't hurt you (almost always) to put them in provided the opinion of the community/industry hasn't turned against you. If you have a large array of publications, consider selecting your top three and presenting them under "Selected Publications". Just like any kind of public available information, be aware that there is a wide gamut of opinions on a lot of topics, so anything more controversial will have a lower chance to aid you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Placement is the key

It generally never hurts including the information in your resume. However, **where**, **what**, and **how much** you choose to place in your resume is something you can put some thought into.

- Is including a select few of them going to influence the chances of you getting hired? If yes, sure display the section prominently, maybe even on the first page.
- Is it just an additional item showcasing one of your skill/achievement? You can put it in a later page.

To conclude, the inclusion may play a crucial role in one job and not make much of a difference in another. You'd be better off maintaining different versions of your resume and/or customize it based on the job you are applying for.

You should even consider handpicking which publications to list in your resume, based on the role, when applying for a particular job.

If you maintain a personal website, it would be a good idea to link to the articles from your website. You can always mention your website address in the resume, as it lets hiring personnel easily browse through any/all information about you.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, your publications are great to include on your resume if you're eager to share them and believe they demonstrate your capabilities.**

Beyond your technical knowledge, your publications demonstrate:

- **Your ability to effectively document what you know** - you're able to write down your own knowledge in a way that is easy for others to understand and make use of
- **Your willingness to share knowledge** - you've made efforts to share what you know and you'll likely take time to share your knowledge with future colleagues
- **Your personal interest in your professional work** - you're not the kind of person who's in it just for a paycheck, you actually enjoy what you're doing
- **You're open to criticism and broad review of your work** - You posted your compositions for large audiences, including topical experts, to review and criticize
- **You can "get the job done"** - you took the articles to completion, having a real publication is a rare accomplishment

Comment: This is borrowing heavily from a similar answer to a similar question: [Should I put programming books I wrote a few years ago on my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/138089/should-i-put-programming-books-i-wrote-a-few-years-ago-on-my-resume/138092#138092)