# May I include non-academic publications on my Linkedin profile?

Tags: resume, linkedin

In the Profile Section on Linkedin there is the possibility to add Publications (See Add Profile Sections > Accomplishments > Publication).

I collaborated as a comic artist and author with several publishing companies and online magazines for some years, therefore many of my illustrations, texts and so on have been published both on the web and on paper-based magazines.

I also have a personal blog where I published some of my illustrations.

I wonder if I might include some of them on the "Publications" section mentioned above. For instance, I may add the URL of my website; and I may take pictures of some of the paper-based publications, and add them by specifying the name of the monthly magazine in the field "Publisher"...

Although I will not keep working in that field, I suppose that including these publications might be useful to show my proficiency in my previous work experiences... But I'm not sure whether to include this "artistic" publications in the "publications" section of Linkedin, or if it's related to academic publications only.

Is it recommendable to include non-academic publications on Linkedin?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, your publications are great to include on LinkedIn if you're eager to share them.**

Any published work is relevant for the publications section of your resume and LinkedIn. Articles, artworks, etc. are all great to include.

Beyond your artistic skills, your publications demonstrate:

- **Your ability to effectively collaborate** - you've worked with others to create something great - this is great evidence of your ability to cooperate.
- **You're open to criticism and broad review of your work** - your compositions can be seen by large audiences to review and criticize.
- **You can "get the job done"** - you took the comics to completion, having a real publication is a rare accomplishment.
- **You have diverse interests** - your interests help current and potential colleagues get to know you. It's great to show off what you do outside of your day job.

Comment: Borrowing heavily from a similar answer to a similar question: [Are professional publications and journal articles worthwhile to include in resume for specialty role in IT?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/139612/are-professional-publications-and-journal-articles-worthwhile-to-include-in-resu/139643#139643)

Comment: Furthermore, being able to draw like a comic artist can be a useful communication skill. For example, some important presentation could benefit from a simple personalised drawing instead of a stock image.